# Two Servers Alike In Dignity (@Inject results in null reference)

Tags: java, linux, dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb

I am very new to the java application server scene, and so I've been attempting to remedy that with a simple application.

I have installed Glassfish 4 on my mac, and have written a simple app that listens for an http request, parses out the query parameters, and passes them to a jvm queue to be processed by another object.

On my Mac, the code works as expected. I submit a request, things get parsed and passed, and all is well. If I deploy my war file to my linux box (using the glassfish admin console) things get odd. Both my mac and linux (ubuntu) machine have glassfish 4, both current with updates as of yesterday. I use a separate object (of a class annotated as @stateless) that's injected into the HTTPServlet object. On the linux machine, the injected object is null. On the mac, it has a value.

Here's some code:

Here's the HttpServlet:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Enumeration;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/en" )
public class ERoute extends HttpServlet {
    **@Inject
    ENotificationSender sender;**

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ENotification message=new ENotification();

        Enumeration paramNames=request.getParameterNames();
        while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                    // assemble the message to put on the queue
        }

        **sender.sendMessage(message);**

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

And the ENotificationSender:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.*;

@Stateless
@JMSDestinationDefinitions(
        {@JMSDestinationDefinition(name="jms.BQueue", interfaceName="javax.jms.Queue")}
)
public class ENotificationSender {
    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/BSample")
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/BQueue")
    private Queue theQueue;

    public void sendMessage(ENotification message) {
        context.createProducer().send(theQueue, message);
    }
}
```

The line **sender.sendMessage(message);** above results in a null pointer exception, but only on the linux machine.

Here's the error:

```
[2014-02-22T10:50:33.214-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=93 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1393084233214] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[ERoute]: Servlet.service() for servlet ERoute threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ERoute.doGet(ERoute.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at RouteFilter.doFilter(RouteFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

I'm assuming that my knowledge of how things work together is not sufficient here (and I would attest that that is true), but I'm unsure why it would work on the mac and not on the linux machine. Both run java 1.7, glassfish 4.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Two notes: Make inline notes using comments, not by changing your code (typos could be part of whatever problem is involved), and while your title is amusing, it's better to be direct and searchable.

Comment: +1 - Shakespeare reference.

Comment: @chrylis, good points. thank you.

Comment: needed question > Are you completely sure that the Queue is correctly configured in the linux system?, sometimes happens ;)